# Django Admin Automation to Send Daily Query Activity to Admin

Tags: django

Did a small app for parking and i want to ask your advice/help on how to make an automation that will submit daily report to the admin.

Currently use Dango SQL-Explorer 3rd pty plugin to show you this.

Basically my SQL query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM parcare_parking
WHERE parking_on = tomorrow()
```

In the explorer i can see nice this window. I would like each day at 18:00 to receive the snapshot of this query. How can i do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Two things**

Add a Django template that generates the output in the desired tabular form

For scheduling the task to run periodically, add an entry to the cron list. eg wget http://yourdomain.com/your-route

Or use Django Celery http://docs.celeryproject.org for periodic execution (A more robust package)